# Getting very low accuracy using lstm for imdb reviews

Tags: python, lstm, word2vec, loss

I have converted the imdb reviews into 300 dimension using Word2Vec.

I have kept embedding_vecor_length = 32, input_length = 300 of 25000 reviews.

I am getting very poor accuracy and high loss.

At the end of 10 epochs I get accuracy of 0.4977 and loss of 0.6932.

```
    embedding_vecor_length = 32
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(25000, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=300))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics['accuracy'])
```

What should I add or remove so that accuracy increases and loss decreases?

Answer (score 1):

25000 seems to be the number of samples you have, not the input dimension of the embedding layer. I think you should check which dimensions you want in that function. I think, without seeing your data, what you actually want is:

```
model.add(Embedding(300, embedding_vecor_length))
```

But since you've already used word2vec, that is already an embedding! You don't need an embedding layer. I think you should remove it and then see your accuracy.

Comment: I tried the way suggested above no much change.By removing the embedding layer I just commented it out which gave me an error ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling build() or calling fit() with some data. Or specify input_shape or batch_input_shape in the first layer for automatic build.

Comment: Yes, when you start a model you have to specify the input shape. model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(sequence_length,300)))

Answer (score 0):

you can use pretrained word embedding  glove, you can use glove.6B.50d.txt, which you can download from the http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip ,
use 50d

```
def read_glove_vecs(glove_file):
    with open(glove_file,'r',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
         words = set()
         word_to_vec_map = {}
         for line in f:
             line = line.strip().split()
             curr_word = line[0]
             words.add(curr_word)
             word_to_vec_map[curr_word] = np.array(line[1:], dtype=np.float64)

         i = 1
         words_to_index = {}
         index_to_words = {}
         for w in sorted(words):
             words_to_index[w] = I
             index_to_words[i] = w
             i = i + 1
    return words_to_index, index_to_words, word_to_vec_map
```

Now call the above function, which will return

```
word_to_index, index_to_word, word_to_vec_map = read_glove_vecs('data/glove.6B.50d.txt')
```

Now create word embedding from these pretrained word

```
vocab_len = len(word_to_index) 
emb_dim = 50 # the above word vector are trained for 50 dim
emb_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_len, emb_dim))

for word, index in word_to_index.items():
    emb_matrix[index,:] = word_to_vec_map[word]
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_len, emb_dim, trainable = False)
embedding_layer.build((None,))

embedding_layer.set_weights([emb_matrix])
```

Now use this, embedding layer in your model, which will improve your accuracy